# Add module to Test Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

To a test class, Im trying to add a module:

```
require "test_helper"
require "before_find_helper"

class User::FindOrCreateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include BeforeFindHelper
```

the module looks like this one:

```
module BeforeFindHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  self.before do
    class FakeController < ApplicationController
     ......
    end
  end
end
```

Basically before the  `before`-block was defined in the controller and **everything worked fine**:

```
  before do
    class FakeController < ApplicationController
     ......
    end
  end
```

But now with the included module I get this error when running the Test:

undefined method `before' for BeforeFindHelper:Module

**How can I get the tests working again?** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you include a module, you are pulling in all methods *defined* in the module.  `before` is a method *called by* the module. That is, the `before` code is calling a method named `before` and passing it the block of code to execute before the test.

One hopeful alternative would be to define the method that defines the class in the module, and call it from your test class with in the `before` call.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to define a class in a method. However, it *is* possible to define a class in a lambda.  So your module method could return a lambda that, when called, defines the class:

```
module BeforeFindHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def fn_define_fake_controller_class
    -> do
      class FakeController < ApplicationController
       ......
      end
    end
  end
end


class User::FindOrCreateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include BeforeFindHelper

  before { fn_define_fake_controller_class.() }
end
```

That all said, one of my pet peeves about Rails code is that it uses `include` far too often.  It's not much more difficult to define the method on the module level and preface its name with the module name when you call it.  This plainly shows the reader where to find the called method if he/she wants to examine it.  Here's what that might look like:

```
module BeforeFindHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.fn_define_fake_controller_class
    -> do
      class FakeController < ApplicationController
       ......
      end
    end
  end
end


class User::FindOrCreateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  before { BeforeFindHelper.fn_define_fake_controller_class.() }
end
```

The only differences are 1) the `include` has been removed because it is no longer necessary, 2) that when `fn_define_fake_controller_class` is defined, it is preceded by `self.`, and 3) when the method is called, it is disambiguated with the module name: `BeforeFindHelper.fn_define_fake_controller_class.()`.

Come to think of it, this could be simplified somewhat by calling the lambda in the method that defines it, so that in your test code you're calling a method, and not a lambda returned by a method:

```
module BeforeFindHelper
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def self.define_fake_controller_class
    -> do
      class FakeController < ApplicationController
       ......
      end
    end.()
  end
end


class User::FindOrCreateTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  before { BeforeFindHelper.define_fake_controller_class }
end
```

The differences are 1) the method is renamed to indicate that is doing the defining and not returning a lambda (fn); 2) the lambda is invoked immediately after its definition (with `.()`); 3) the call is renamed and is a regular method call.

Comment: Hi, great answer. Really like the explanation. But trying it out Im getting now the `before_find_helper.rb:6: class definition in method body (SyntaxError)`? Im doing something wrong? Thanks again!

Comment: Sounds you're defining a method instead of a lambda.  You need to use `->` and not `def`.

Comment: If you want, show me your code in a Github gist or the like.

Comment: Yes in `/test/before_find_helper.rb` the `module` is located. In `/test/services/user/after_register/redirect_back_service.rb` my test class is located. The test class is named `class User::AfterRegister::RedirectBackServiceTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase`. In order to let rails find the module i'm calling `require "before_find_helper"`. And thats I think were the problem is?

Comment: I can't picture all that.  Could you post your code somewhere, such as a Github gist, or on http://pastebin.com/, or maybe add it to your question?